# Applying the main function to my bluej project / Making my bluej program a executable .jar

Tags: java, executable, program-entry-point, executable-jar, bluej

```
    public class Player
{
        // Fields for tracking Class, health and name
        private String name;
        private String playerClass;
        private int health;

        // Array of classes
        String[] classes = {
            "Warrior", "Mage", "Rogue",
            "Hunter", "Druid", "Priest",
            "Paladin", "Monk", "Warlock"
        };
        //Available Classes are "Warrior", "Mage", "Rogue", "Hunter", "Druid", "Priest", "Paladin", "Monk" and "Warlock"  

        // ##Constructor##
        public Player(String setName, String setClass)
        {....
}
```

Is the beginning of my code, with the constructor of the program, how do i apply the main function to this so that I can create an executable .jar file?
It's written in Bluej all within one class.

Edit - I understand i need a main function, and kind know how it works. However what do i put in the brackets of the main function in this scenario to get things rolling?

Comment: How do you run it in BlueJ if it doesn't have a main method? How have you managed to write so much code without having written a main method, which is the first thing you do when learning Java?

Comment: It's how they showed us how to code, and use Bluej's functions to check our code.  To do the whole main function we were just told to read a section in our appendix which I can't get my head around.

Comment: Sounds like a horrible way to teach programming. I mean the first thing you're supposed to do is [Hello, world!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program), and you can't do that without writing a main method.

Comment: I assume the main function is part of some of the next lectures as it's part of our first assignment.  So far we're only gone over the basic functions in java.

Comment: So you've gone through the basics of running, and in next lectures you'll be learning to walk. Let's hope this is some horrible unfortunate oversight and doesn't represent the quality of the education in total.

Comment: I hope not either, our book doesn't explain the main function at all, except in an appendix in the back of the book. It's mostly coding within Bluej

Comment: Well, I recommend Googling for some simple tutorials (that **don't** use BlueJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a stand-alone Java application, there is needed the main method with strictly predefined modifiers and paramteres:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

In the BlueJ, you can start the program by clicking the right button on the class in the diagram and selecting `void main(String[] args)` or create a new instance of the class (in your case `new Circle`).

For more information, read this article: [Getting Started with BlueJ](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/scottm/cs307/handouts/BlueJProjectInstructions.html).

Comment: What do i put in the brackets of the function to get this started though?

Comment: Edited, you should create a new instance of the class `Circle`.

Comment: You lost me, where do I use an instance named Circle?

Comment: Edit - I understand the circle referance but the getting started with bluej link doesn't explain what to put inside the brackets either, they just create it, delete the content and sim salabim it's connected to the other class

Comment: Like using any other application, you pass variables to `String[] args` as the starting variables. Usually you leave it empty and work with the content inside the `main` method. BlueJ works little different, because you can simulate the main method with creating an instance yourself.. really simply said. Normally you would call `Circle c = new Circle()` inside the main method.

Comment: I took some time and asked my lecturer, My main issue was that i was calling the class to create an object, but forgot to give it any parameters.  But you were very helpfull in making the launch class! Thanks alot :)